# Bash script - Construct a single line out of many lines having duplicates in a single column

Tags: bash, duplicates

I have an instrumented log file that have 6 lines of duplicated first column as  below.

```
//SC001@1/1/1@1/1,get,ClientStart,1363178707755
//SC001@1/1/1@1/1,get,TalkToSocketStart,1363178707760
//SC001@1/1/1@1/1,get,DecodeRequest,1363178707765
//SC001@1/1/1@1/1,get-reply,EncodeReponse,1363178707767
//SC001@1/1/1@1/2,get,DecodeRequest,1363178708765
//SC001@1/1/1@1/2,get-reply,EncodeReponse,1363178708767
//SC001@1/1/1@1/2,get,TalkToSocketEnd,1363178708770
//SC001@1/1/1@1/2,get,ClientEnd,1363178708775
//SC001@1/1/1@1/1,get,TalkToSocketEnd,1363178707770
//SC001@1/1/1@1/1,get,ClientEnd,1363178707775
//SC001@1/1/1@1/2,get,ClientStart,1363178708755
//SC001@1/1/1@1/2,get,TalkToSocketStart,1363178708760
```

Note: , (comma) is the delimiter here

Like wise there are many duplicate first column values (IDs) in the log file (above example having only two values (IDs); //SC001@1/1/1@1/1 and //SC001@1/1/1@1/2)  I need to consolidate log records as below format.

```
ID,ClientStart,TalkToSocketStart,DecodeRequest,EncodeReponse,TalkToSocketEnd,ClientEnd

//SC001@1/1/1@1/1,1363178707755,1363178707760,1363178707765,1363178707767,1363178707770,1363178707775
//SC001@1/1/1@1/2,1363178708755,1363178708760,1363178708765,1363178708767,1363178708770,1363178708775
```

I suppose to have a bash script for this exercise and appreciate an expert support for this. Hope there may be a sed or awk solution which is more efficient.

Thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
sort -t, -k4n,4 file | awk -F, '{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1] FS $NF:$NF;}END{for(i in a){print i","a[i];}}'
```

`sort` command sorts  the file on the basis of the last(4th) column. `awk` takes the sorted input and forms an array where the 1st field is the key, and the value is combination of values of the last column.